# Clearing a Draft.js textarea in automated testing

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, draftjs

In my react app I am using a component that is building on top of draft.js.

Unfortunately I can not interact with it as I would with a normal textarea when using `react-testing`.

I want to input text, clear that text and then input new text. With an empty draft.js editor it is easy enough:

```js
const textarea = screen.getByRole('textbox');
const event = createEvent.paste(textarea, {
  clipboardData: {
    types: ['text/plain'],
    getData: () => 'MyText',
  },
});
fireEvent(textarea, event);
```

I now want to clear the input in order to paste a new input. If I just invoke a second paste event, it will paste the data before what is already in the textarea so:

```js
const textarea = screen.getByRole('textbox');
const event = createEvent.paste(textarea, {
  clipboardData: {
    types: ['text/plain'],
    getData: () => 'MyText',
  },
});
fireEvent(textarea, event);
fireEvent(textarea, event);
```

will result in the content of the textbox being `MyTextMyText`.

I tried using the change event to clear the textbox:

```js
const textarea = screen.getByRole('textbox');
const changeEvent = createEvent.change(textarea, {
  target: {
    value: ''
  },
});
fireEvent(textarea, changeEvent);
```

resulting in: `The given element does not have a value setter`

So my question is: **What is the correct way to clear a draft.js textarea between pasting new content into it?**

Comment: try to use select-all then delete events to clear. I suppose your testing framework have this two events.

Comment: @JiangYD thank you. Although this did not work it allowed me to look into a different solution. I am now firing a 'Delete' keyDown event as often as long the string is to clear it.
I tried to fire a [CTRL] + A keyDown event to select all, but for some reason this is not registered as a keyDown event. Neither is sending an simple 'A' keyDown event. Not sure why this is exactly, but as long as Delete works it solves my issue.